# TYPO3 setting phpTimeZone in LocalConfiguration.php file

Tags: php, typo3

I have set `[SYS][phpTimeZone] = Europe/Berlin` in `LocalConfiguration.php` but the server shows UTC instead of the correct time zone despite the entry `[SYS][phpTimeZone] = Europe/Berlin`.

Comment: Where do you see the wrong time? In the backend or frontend? Is there maybe an AdditionalConfiguration.php file in place which overwrites LocalConfiguration.php?

Comment: It show wrong time in frontend. and there is no issue of overwriting AdditionalConfiguration.php or overwrites LocalConfiguration.php